# How to set default Data Table Page Length to 100 in complete project?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have a large report section in my project and have 100's of report using data table,with some customize data table functionality. Now my client want :-

1. Default page length for all data table reports to be increased from 10 to 100 , which should apply by default to all existing data tables and new also.
2. Data table searching should also be cached (i,e if i filter a record with city name X, it returned 10 records , now i click details of any 1 of them which opens a new page. ) what he wants exactly lies here( if he goes back from details page , the previous search record list of 10 should come, despite of the full record list.)

Hope i was clear with my queries, any suggestion and help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer to this questions when you are using [Yajra Datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).

**For first question:**

You can store page length number in your DB, in some 'settings' table, which can be managed from admins. And get that for all pages. Also you can get that using Laravel Caches, and with that you don't need to retrieve from DB for each time. Instead you will retrieve that from caches, which will speed up your app.
Now assume you alredy got that number [like this, using off. doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#obtaining-a-cache-instance):

```
$page_length = Cache::get('page_length');
```

You can create some GeneralController which will extends from Controller, then in constructor you can write that and share that for all blades like this:

```
View::share('page_length', $page_length); // Illuminate Support Facade
```

Or you can pass that $page_length in some "protected $page_length = null;", init in constructor of GeneralController, and use that in your other controllers which extends from GeneralController.

So now you can get that in blades. You can use that like this

```
var YajraDataTable = $('#yajra_datatable').DataTable({
            "pageLength": parseInt("{{ $page_length }}"),
```

Answer for second question I will write with real example little bit later.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use [Yajra DataTable](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) follow the link for understanding.
This is [Demo link](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-5-8-datatables-ajax-crud-tutorial/) which will help.

Yajra DataTable is ajax datatable which offer number of record per page and searching.Even I am also using the same.